# Some questions in function matplotlib.pyplot.hist in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a homework which I need to draw the histogram of lena(name of a famous picture).
And there is something wrong in my histogram.I followed the example code in matplot.org And here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def rgb2gray(rgb):                                        # rgb to grey
    temp = np.dot(rgb[..., :3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])
    new = np.zeros([512,512], 'uint8')
    for i in range(512):
        for j in range(512):
            new[i, j] = round( temp[i, j])                #float to int
    return new

lena = plt.imread("E:\lena.bmp")
lena_gray = rgb2gray(lena)
len, width = lena_gray.shape

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(lena_gray, normed=1)
print(n ,bins, patches)

plt.show()
```

But the histogram I get is:

[image: histogram.png]

The mistake is when I magnify the bottom of the picture:

[image: magnify.png]

As you see,there is so many bins between the 66 and 67.But in my code,the first parameter in function hist is lena_gray. And the numbers in array lena_grey is all integer. So I want to know why I have so many bins between two number in histogram or why I have decimals in my x-axis.

Comment: You should print your output instead of posting a link to an image

Comment: Perhaps link to the example code?  This appears to be the typical behavior for matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handing a matrix to `plt.hist`, that is interpreted as a list of arrays to process. See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html). The histogram for each of the 512 columns is calculated and displayed. If you reshape the image matrix to a vector first, the histogram turns out fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def rgb2gray(rgb):                                        # rgb to grey
    return np.dot(rgb[..., :3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]).astype(int)

lena = plt.imread("E:\lena.bmp")
lena_gray = rgb2gray(lena)
len, width = lena_gray.shape

# use np.reshape to transform matrix to vector
n ,bins, patches = plt.hist(np.reshape(lena_gray,(-1,1)), normed=1)
print(n ,bins, patches)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Since the order of pixels is irrelevant for histogramming, you may also simply flatten the array: `plt.hist(lena_gray.flatten(), )`